# How do I get blending to work with lighting and material?

Tags: opengl, graphics, lighting

Which alpha should I change? Diffuse, specular, or ambient?

Comment: That depends on what kind of blending you're looking for, but most likely you want to change the diffuse

Comment: so we generally only change the diffuse. Does changing the other alphas suppose to do anything?

Comment: When you decrease the diffuse alpha it makes the main color part transparent, when you decrease the specular it makes the bright highlights transparent. If you know what each of these things are it should be pretty easy to predict the result. Otherwise it should be equally as easy to test it out yourself ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said exactly what you're doing, so I'm going to assume that you are setting the colors of an object directly with `glLightParameter`, rather than fetching them from a texture.

To do what you want, which is have a single number have total control over the transparency of the object, you want to set ambient, diffuse, and specular color alphas to **zero**. You then use the *emissive* alpha to set the transparency.

If you're using textures, then you need to do more work. You need to use a proper texture environment model that takes the alpha directly from the fixed-function lighting with no modifications.

Or you can just use shaders and ditch all this fixed-function nonsense. It will save you *so* many headaches.

Answer (score 0):

use `GL_SRC_ALPHA , GL_ONE`as parameter in `glBlendFunc();`

Ex:

```
glColor4f(1.0,1.0,1.0,alpha_value);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA , GL_ONE);
```

Replace alpha_value as your requirement....`